# SELECT every second row without auto_increment

Tags: mysql

How can I select every second row in MySQL, without using any data of the table or some auto_increment?
Something like

```
SELECT EVERY SECOND ROW FROM `table`;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no SQL mechanism for select every other row.

You will have to use an user-defined auto increment variable as follows:

### ODD

```
SET @inc = 0;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *,@inc:=1-@inc autoinc
FROM mytable) A
WHERE autoinc = 1 ORDER BY id;
```

### EVEN

```
SET @inc = 1;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *,@inc:=1-@inc autoinc
FROM mytable) A
WHERE autoinc = 1 ORDER BY id;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## MORE INSIGHTS

If the table is very large, try using a LEFT JOIN of id

### ODD

```
SET @inc = 0;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id,@inc:=1-@inc autoinc
FROM mytable ORDER BY id) A
LEFT JOIN mytable USING (id) 
WHERE autoinc = 1;
```

### EVEN

```
SET @inc = 1;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id,@inc:=1-@inc autoinc
FROM mytable ORDER BY id) A
LEFT JOIN mytable USING (id) 
WHERE autoinc = 1;
```

## PAGINATION

### ODD

```
SET @inc = 0;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id,@inc:=1-@inc autoinc
FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,20) A
LEFT JOIN mytable USING (id) 
WHERE autoinc = 1;
```

### EVEN

```
SET @inc = 1;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT id,@inc:=1-@inc autoinc
FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,20) A
LEFT JOIN mytable USING (id) 
WHERE autoinc = 1;
```